# Count the number of events on a day of the month in MySQl

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, where-clause

I want to count the number of events that occur on any given day of the month, ie 1st to 31st. not Month specific. So that I can see at what time of the month the most events are happening.

I can get the total the number of events on a specific dateTime that spans a couple of months with this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(created_at) 
  FROM loan 
 WHERE DATE(created_at) >= DATE('2020-08-01') 
   AND DATE(created_at) <= DATE('2020-12-31') 
 GROUP BY DATE(created_at);
```

For example, 10 events happen on the 7th day of the month, 50 events happen on the 29th. So I can see that there is more activity at the end of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DAY()` instead of `DATE()`:

```
SELECT DAY(created_at), COUNT(*)
FROM loan
WHERE created_at >= '2020-08-01' AND
      created_at < '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY DAY(created_at);
```

Note that you don't need all the `DATE()` functions in the `WHERE` clause.  That can slow down performance if indexes could be used for the `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider aggregating by `DAY()` rather than `DATE()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DAY(created_at) 
FROM loan 
WHERE created_at >= '2020-08-01' AND created_at < '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY DAY(created_at);
```

Note that I changed the `where` clause so it no function is applied on the column being filtered; this is more efficient, especially if you have an index on `created_at`.